# Fair locking in ReeantrantReadWriteLock

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java Concurrency In Practice by B. Goetz, section 13.5 said:

> In Java 5.0, the read lock behaves more like a semaphore than a lock,
>   maintaining only the count of active readers, not their identities.
>   The behavior was changed in Java 6 to keep track also of which threads
>   have been granted the read lock6.
>
> 6 One reason for this change is that under java 5.0, the lock
>   implementation cannot distinguish between a thread requesting the read
>   lock for the first time and reentrant lock request, *which would make*
>   ***fair*** *read-write lock deadlock-prone*.

My question is what's wrong with fairness? Why was the unfair read-write lock shielded from the deadlock?

Could you explain what he meant? I mean in which circumstances does a ***fair*** read-write lock under Java 5 cause a deadlock? And if it behaved like a `Semaphore` why didn't the fair `Semaphore` cause a deadlock?

Comment: You might want to stop and ask, what's _right_ with fairness?  In a desk-top or server environment, processes often compete with each other for CPU time.  "Fairness" in the scheduler insures that each competing process gets a fair share.  But within a single program, threads should _cooperate_ instead of competing.  And, when there's work to be done, it should not matter which thread does the work.  If there's two worker threads in a pool, and only one and a half threads-worth of work for them to do, it won't hurt anything if the workload is not distributed "fairly".

Comment: @jameslarge in the context of acquiring locks fairness indicates that threads competing for the same lock, acquire it in the order they requested it.

Comment: @bowmore, I understand that "fairness" in a scheduler is not exactly the same thing as a "fair" implementation of a mutex, but it's not coincidence that they share the same name.  They both are meant to insure that threads/processes get "fair" access when they compete for resources.  I question the importance of "fair" mutexes because, when I write multi-threaded code, I don't want my threads to compete fairly:  I want them to not compete at all.  That's a hard goal to achieve, but IMO, worth striving for when performance is an issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the implementation does not know whether a requesting thread already has the lock, in case of a fair locking strategy new request from the same thread would be queued after prior requests, possibly from other threads.

If there are write requests from other threads preceding this reentrant request, they cannot advance since the thread holding the lock is also blocked waiting for its reentrant request. Resulting in deadlock.

An unfair locking strategy does not suffer from this problem as the reentrant request can jump the queue (barging) and doesn't need to wait for prior requests.

Semaphore does not suffer from this problem because it is not meant to be reentrant.

Comment: _Semaphore does not suffer from this problem because it is not meant to be reentrant._ Well, it's not quite clear. From what you explain I'd say that they don't suffer from this as there's no "read"/"write"-semaphores.

Comment: @DmitriiBundin What I mean is that, the same thread asking another permit from a Semaphore should get a second permit, it doesn't matter that it already got one. It's obviously possible to get into a deadlock situation too, but this would be the client's fault, and not of Semaphore's implementation.